Why is the exported variable unaltered after I modify it in the imported module?
In a boot file of a quasar application extension register.ts, I do:
let appUrl = '';

const bootFunc = ({app, store, router}) => {

    console.log('In app-extension boot file');

    appUrl = app.config.globalProperties.$appUrl;

};

export {bootFunc as default, appUrl };

the variable appUrl gets exported, then the bootFunc gets called when the application extension is initialized. appUrl is properly initialized.
appUrl is imported and used by another file. I am expecting appUrl to be set at that point, however when I access it is still unaltered.
Why does the bootFunc not override the value?

In JavaScript, a variable contains a reference to an object. An assignment changes the reference in the variable. It doesn't modify the object.
appUrl contains a reference to the data. export {bootFunc as default, appUrl }; exports a copy of this reference. appUrl = app.config.globalProperties.$appUrl; assigns another reference to the variable, a reference to a different object. It doesn't modify the first object. Always remember: If you want to modify existing references, you must not use the assignment operator.
That's basic JavaScript. You don't need modules, imports and exports to reproduce it:


let appUrl = '';
let appUrlCopy = appUrl;
appUrl = 'url';
console.log('appUrl:', appUrl);
console.log('appUrlCopy:', appUrlCopy);



